# Html5 vs Html4 question about size in KB comparison

Tags: html

I would like to know if by using HTML5 is really lighter in KB comparing against the same layout built on HTML4.

Answer (score 3):

You save a few bytes in the Doctype and gain a few bytes by using new semantic elements instead of divs.

The difference is **not** significant and size should not be a factor when deciding between HTML 4 and 5.

Comment: Yes, at the end Google likes lighter pages but prefer semantic stuff. Then i see that you gain in one hand but lose in other. Thanks for the clear response.

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 is still in draft. Yes, HTML is not as cluttered as HTML 4 and so HTML 5 is little faster. But then, making a webpage also requires other languages like CSS & Javascript, so if you're into serious webmaking, size question of HTML is not a problem.

Comment: Can you define "less cluttered" please? And explain how it makes HTML 5 faster.

Comment: @Quentin http://stackoverflow.com/a/4773978/889750 <- It's last few lines describes what I mean