# How does a Web browser differentiate between HTML5 and HTML4?

Tags: html, browser, html4

How does a Web browser differentiate between HTML5 and HTML4?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the key difference between HTML 4 and HTML 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134727/whats-the-key-difference-between-html-4-and-html-5)

Comment: See [Don't forget to add a doctype](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Doctype)

Comment: So the answer is : DTD declaration ?

Comment: @Dominik The OP seems to be asking *how the browser knows* the difference between the two, not *what is* the difference between them.

Comment: yeah that's my question

Comment: @AHmédNet Yes, the browser determines the markup's version according to the doctype declaration.

Comment: Thank's @ Boaz and another thanks to @Dominik

Comment: @Boaz: good point, the two questions are really not duplicates.

Comment: Browsers don't differentiate between HTML5 and HTML4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp), the following DOCTYPE defines a document as HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

And the three types of HTML4 are defined by the following DOCTYPE declarations:

HTML 4.01 Strict

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

HTML 4.01 Transitional

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

HTML 4.01 Frameset

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
```