# What are the key differences between HTML 4 and HTML 5? How to know, which HTML to use?

Tags: html

I want to know the key differences between html 4 and html 5? Should I prefer html 4 or html 5 for development? What are the benefits of HTML 5 and how to know if a website is using html 5 or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134727/whats-the-key-difference-between-html-4-and-html-5

Comment: Surprisingly this link did not showed up on google when I searched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to check whether the website is using HTML5 or not is the doctype. HTML5 has a really easy doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`. So if you do not see the website having HTML 4.01 in the doctype and just has a simple `<!DOCTYPE html>`, that website is on HTML5.

Please use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134727/whats-the-key-difference-between-html-4-and-html-5) Hemdip provided to get the key differences between HTML4 and HTML 5.

HTML5 is the new standard which introduces a lot of new features such as `<canvas>`,`<video>`,`<audio>` and `<track>` tags and updated a lot of other elements([more of that here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/28-html5-features-tips-and-techniques-you-must-know--net-13520)). Hence you should definitely try to use HTML 5 wherever possible.

You can follow [this link](http://allroundexpert.blogspot.in/2014/06/difference-between-html-4-and-html-5.html) where you can get complete tabular difference in both. Both are compared on tag basis. Which are new tags in HTML5 and which are removed from HTML5

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 is basically an update to HTML 4. This means that everything HTML 4 is also in HTML 5. It's similar to updating an app on your phone—often the app adds new features to what is already there.

So, in reality, every page has the ability to use HTML 5 features because this is the most current version of HTML. The only time this isn't true is when it is otherwise stated in the `<!DOCTYPE>`which appears almost always as the first line of the page code.

This question has been answered before: [What's the key difference between HTML 4 and HTML 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134727/whats-the-key-difference-between-html-4-and-html-5)